# Django - How to combine 2 queryset and filter to get same element in both queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model:

```
class LocationItem(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_qty = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Example: I have some data like this:

```
------------------------------
| ID | Item | Location | Qty |
------------------------------
| 1  |  1   |    1     |  10 |
------------------------------
| 2  |  2   |    1     |  5  |
------------------------------
| 3  |  1   |    2     |  2  |
------------------------------
| 4  |  3   |    1     |  4  |
------------------------------
| 5  |  3   |    2     |  20 |
------------------------------
```

I have 2 queryset to get items of each location:

```
location_1 = LocationItem.objects.filter(location_id=1)
location_2 = LocationItem.objects.filter(location_id=2)
```

Now I want to combine 2 queryset above into 1 and filter only same items in both 2 location such as result of this example above is `[Item 1, Item 3]` because item 1 and 3 belong to both location 1 and 2

Comment: So what do you think the result query or list should look like in your case, in the example?

Comment: result of this example above is [1, 3] because item 1 and 3 belong to both location 1 and 2

Comment: And if there's gonna be another row | 5 | 2 | 2 | 30 | ? What would be the result?

Comment: the result is [Item 1, Item 3, Item 2] if have row | 5 | 2 | 2 | 30 |

Comment: So you need both unique Items and unique Locations? :)

Comment: Yes, my friend. Please help me resolve it!

Answer (score 3):

You can combine django query set using following expression

```
location_1 = LocationItem.objects.filter(location_id=1)
location_2 = LocationItem.objects.filter(location_id=2)

location = location_1 | location_2
```

Above combine expression works on same model filter query set.

Try this one

```
from django.db.models import Count
dupes = LocationItem.objects.values('item__id').annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=1)
LocationItem.objects.filter(item__=[i['item__id'] for i in dupes]).distinct('item__id')
```

May be above solution help.

Comment: @trent fernandez See updated answer may be it's help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both conditions to be true, then you need the `AND` operator (`&`)

```
from django.db.models import Q

Q(location_1) & Q(location_2)
```

Comment: I want to get a queryset store only same items of location_1 and location_2. In this case is [1, 3] because item 1 and 3 belong to both location 1 and 2

Comment: I'm so sorry the result of your code is wrong because it will get all element of 2 queryset while I just wanna get items in location 1 that also appearance in location 2

Comment: I'm so sorry but the result return is empty QuerySet with `Q(location_1) & Q(location_2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by piping the filters. The result of a filter is a queryset. So after the first filtering, the result will be `[Item1, Item2    , Item3]` and then second filter will be applied on the resulting queryset which leads `[Item1, Item3]`. For eg.

```
Item.objects.filter(locationitem_set__location = 1).filter(locationitem_set__location = 2)
```

P.S. Not tested. Hope this works.

Comment: Sorry I'm filtering in model `LocationItem` not in model `Item`. How can I filter like you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location1_items_pk = LocationItem.objects.filter(
    location_id=1
).values_list("item_pk", flat=true)

Result = Location.objects.filter(
    item_pk__in=location1_items_pk, location_id=2
)
```

Comment: It Work. Thank you so much! ^_^

Comment: You're welcome. feel free to select it as the right answer if it is the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: Certainly  works but it leads to a subquery which will be lower performance in many cases. Additionally this actually works as two separate queries